# <DIV> shows 3 images instead of 1

Tags: php, image, layout, html

I am new to the community, and this is my first question so far.

I got stuck an hour ago on this. Session checks if user is logged in or not then displays either `login-form_eng.php` or `logout-form_eng.php` with include. Problem is the image shown is displayed 3 times and I am only calling the include function once.

```
<body>

<div id="full-wrap" class="container-wrap">
    <div id="header-wrap" class="secondary-wrap">
        <h1 class="linky-logo" title="elcoma.com"></h1>
        <div id="main-menu-wrap" class="secondary-wrap">
            <table border="0"cellspacing="0"cellpadding="0">
                <tr><td>
                    <a class="linky8"title="Home"onclick="alert('Button Click')">
                </td><td>   
                    <a class="linky2"title="News"onclick="alert('Button Click')">
                </td><td>
                    <a class="linky3"title="Products"onclick="alert('Button Click')">
                </td><td>
                    <a class="linky4"title="Services"onclick="alert('Button Click')">
                </td><td>
                    <a class="linky5"title="About Us"onclick="alert('Button Click')">
                </td><td>
                    <a class="linky6"title="Contact"onclick="alert('Button Click')">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="login-logoff-wrap" class="secondary-wrap">
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo "Welcome back ". $_SESSION['user']. ". Please enjoy your stay at our site!";
    include "logout-form_eng.php";
} else {
    echo "Welcome guest. Please log in or register at our site";
    include "login-form_eng.php";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to how the problem looks like:

[Picture](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?ep85qdegp0ao2et)

**EDIT**

Apparently the two divs around the php script were causing the problem. But I still can't explain why, can somebody explain it to me?

I removed all classes out of all divs one by one then I started deleting the divs. That's how I came to the solution that the two divs around the php login script were somehow "calling" the script? I have no other explanation and I would appreciate a valid one. Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML as well?

Comment: I tried to but since I'm new I can't post an image of how the problem looks like : /

Comment: Upload an image to a host and then link to it.

Comment: <?php session_start(); <- This should go before anything else on the page.

Comment: Alright posted the session on top of everything. However that didn't change anything (for now)
Uploaded the picture on mediafire.

Comment: Good start. Now post login-form_eng.php code and the rendered html output on the page you're viewing. I'd start by placing the `session_start()` in the proper place and try using `include_once` instead of `include` and see if the problem goes away. If it does, you have some weird circular referencing going on.

Answer (score 1):

session_start() should go before all output on the page. The HTML you have preceeding the PHP is considered output.

Since you didn't post the PHP for your two PHP pages, is it possible that there is a redirect in one of these pages that loops back on itself?

Also use include_once() to prevent the page from being included multiple times.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: I tried but there's lot of code mainly from the css and the classes. All that I include are images or already made forms from other pages. I also tried with include_once() but the problem still persists.

Comment: @David What web browser are you using? Did you try a different browser?

Comment: Google Chrome. Didn't try a different one, just took it simple that if Chrome is making problems, then I can imagine IE... that's the backwater hell for all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS. Class `secondary-wrap` is used three times in the DOM. I suppose, that in your CSS the image is used as background in `.secondary-wrap`.

To solve this, you could stick additional class, say `.my-picture` to the topmost `<div>`:

```
<div id="header-wrap" class="secondary-wrap my-picture">
```

and move the background image from `.secondary-wrap` to new `.my-picture`.

---

Or just remove `class="secondary-wrap"` from the two other divs:

```
<div id="main-menu-wrap" class="secondary-wrap">
```

and

```
<div id="login-logoff-wrap" class="secondary-wrap">
```

if there's no other relevant CSS in this class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however no luck - it ain't that.

There is no background image inside secondary-wrap class. All it has is: 
`code`
.secondary-wrap
{
 top: 10%;
 left: 10%;
 position: relative;
 width: 70%;
 clear: both;
}

Still to give it a try I did remove all of them, no luck

Comment: @David If not CSS, then JavaScript. And I'm very certain that it has something to do with `secondary-wrap` class. Are you including some JavaScript libraries in `<head>`? I think that the `New to this site?`  bar with that green Login button is generated with JavaScript and linked to `secondary-wrap` class.